# Uploading data to Shiny for analyses

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to upload a file to Shiny to crunch it and then view it.

I already was able to create a table with a CSV document, but the output myData can't be used as an input for a boxplot or any other graph.

SERVER

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    myData()

  })


}
```

UI

```
library(shiny)

write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10]), 'test.csv')

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents'),
      plotOutput('distPlot')
    )
  )
)
)
```

How can I use the data from the file I uploaded out of the function myData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the functions renderDataTable and dataTableOutput from the DT package for rendering your tables. Your code works fine like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(myData())       
  })
}

write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10]), 'test.csv')

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv',
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                         '.csv'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
      plotOutput('distPlot')
    )
  )
)
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

Also see the article below:

It is also possible to have an user upload csv's to your Shiny app. The code below shows a small example on how this can be achieved. It also includes a radioButton input so the user can interactively choose the separator to be used.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fileInput('target_upload', 'Choose file to upload',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              '.csv'
            )),
  radioButtons("separator","Separator: ",choices = c(";",",",":"), selected=";",inline=TRUE),
  DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table")
)
)

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df_products_upload <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$target_upload
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,sep = input$separator)
    return(df)
  })

  output$sample_table<- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- df_products_upload()
    DT::datatable(df)
  })

}
)

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```