# Shiny apps in R: how to structure them correctly

Tags: r, shiny

I created my first Shiny app, which runs perfectly in my laptop.
However, I need to submit it to my professor and I want to make sure he will be able to run it.
I have a UI file, a server file, a global file and a process file.
The process file stores the data preparation.
The global file reads two RDS files which are the datasets that I use in the server.

1. Where should my libraries be loaded? For example, the app does not run without leaflet, how can I ensure the libraries are run automatically?
2. My RDS files are saved to my local drive, which means that my professor will need to change the path in order to use them, how can avoid this?
3. Shall I put the UI, server and global into **one** R script or is it ok to have them onto two different scripts?

Thank you!

Comment: I solved it by adding the libraries to global, and making the path relative ./filename.rds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you describe your current set up, the most obvious place to load your libraries is at the start of your global file.  (Or at the start of `app.R` if you move to a single file configuration.)  Though not exactly what the `reprex` package is designed for, you could probably use `reprex` to make sure that your code is reproducible and independent of anything you may have overlooked.  (You've already identified the obvious issue with data files.)  Look [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) for more information on `reprex`.
2. Indeed.  This is a problem.  If you *must* load the data from files, you need to find a way of providing them to your professor.  Telling him to edit your code by hand is not a good way to start.  Exactly how to do this depends on the infrastucture your institution has set up, so it's difficult to advise you what to do.  Do you not have a shared area for your course?  Ask your fellow students - or even your professor.
3. Whether you bundle the app in a single file or in seperate files is really a matter of choice.  I don't think there's a wrong way and a right way.  For me, the deciding factor is usually the size of the app.  Large apps get several files.  For small apps, separation is just an unnecessary complication.  Another factor - that doesn't seem to be an issue here - is whether I see the app as a potential front end for some methodology that might be worthy of its own package.  In that case, I develop the app as a front end, and the package itself as separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 and 3 depend on criteria for code quality like performance and maintainability. When the code grows, there will come the point when it is more difficult to handle all code in one file. Once it grows even further you will encounter the point when you need split the app into [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) to keep your code easy to maintain.

Regarding libraries I advise declaring them at the entrance point of an app (though, basically, that is a matter of taste and style). That way, you provide maximum clarity regarding the dependencies of the app. Again, if the app becomes very large and not all parts of the app rely on the same packages, it could improve performance and maintainability that each part loads the packages as required. It could give you a performance advantage when you do not need to load all packages at once. However, that is probably only true for *very large* apps.

However, since this all seems to be an exercise at university, I doubt that your app will reach higher levels of complexity.

Question 2: In a shiny app you can provide `fileInput` widget. This [SO question shows you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449361/uploading-data-to-shiny-for-analyses).